# My Code is only detecting single face only after applying For Loop also

Tags: python, opencv, keras, conv-neural-network, emotion

I am trying to Detect Emotions using my model which takes images as an array, but my code is detecting faces using MTCNN in which the code is detecting only a single face, I have also applied for loop but still it is detecting single face only. Detecting Single face in Single Frame.

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from time import sleep
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from configs import Configs
from PIL import Image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
cfg = Configs()

detector = MTCNN()

model = load_model(cfg.model_path)
emotions = ['Angry', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Happy',
            'Neutral', 'Pain', 'Sad', 'Surprise']

# Sample Video on which we have to Test
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cfg.video_path)
while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    faces = detector.detect_faces(frame)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    if ret == False:
        break
    #for face in faces: 
        # x = faces[0]['box'][0]
        # y = faces[0]['box'][1]
        # w = faces[0]['box'][2]
        # h = faces[0]['box'][3]
        #face = x,y,w,h
    for face in faces:
        x = faces[0]['box'][0]
        y = faces[0]['box'][1]
        w = faces[0]['box'][2]
        h = faces[0]['box'][3]    
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 255), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_gray = cv2.resize(roi_gray, (48, 48), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        if np.sum([roi_gray]) != 0:
            roi = roi_gray.astype('float')/255.0
            roi = img_to_array(roi)
            roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=0)
            prediction = model.predict(roi)[0]
            label = emotions[prediction.argmax()]
            label_position = (x, y)
            cv2.putText(frame, label, label_position,
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        else:
            cv2.putText(frame, 'No Faces', (30, 80),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    size = cv2.resize(frame[:, :, ::1], (560, 640))
    cv2.imshow('Emotion Detector', size)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you are only using faces[0] to compute x,y,w,h. you need to do `for face in faces`: and then compute x,y,w,h for the current face.

Comment: It is still giving an error :  
x = faces[0]['box'][0]
KeyError: 0

Comment: why are you doing x = faces[0]? you need to iterate over faces, if no faces are detected the loop won't iterate over anything. Please update the code in your question with your modifications.

Comment: But one face is detecting, only single face is detecting in single frame
I have updated the changed Code, Please Check!!

Comment: is this really your code? you are still doing `x = faces[0]['box'][0]` instead of accessing the current face as `x = face['box'][0]`. Did you really wrote this code?

Comment: Now It is Detecting Multiple Faces Correctly, Thank you 
Actually, I wrote this code using Haar cascade but using this it was not detecting faces correctly so I used MTCNN instead of Haar cascade that's why I was a little bit confused in the code. So that's why i made mistakes.        Thank You again for helping me out .